# rspec ignore code coverage percentage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, codeship

After I run `rspec` in my `Rails 4` project all the tests pass but I get:

```
Coverage (79.17%) is below the expected minimum coverage (80.00%).
```

as the last line. This is causing `Codeship` to mark the build as failed and email me.

Is there anyway to disable this coverage test or change the minimum coverage percentage?

Comment: Why not improve your test coverage?

Comment: @coreyward Its not a high priority for me right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) you can set the following in your spec helper:

```
SimpleCov.minimum_coverage 90
```

Comment: Ah! I had no idea we were even using that. I inherited this project a few months ago and am still getting acquainted with everything. Thanks!

Comment: It is strange that you are showing how to set it to 90, where the OP cannot even pass 80. Perhaps the OP wanted to set it to 70.